# How do I use setInterval and clearInterval peoperly?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I want this timer to count down from 20 and stop at 0. timerFunction() is called on the click of a button.

```
var time=20;
var clicked=false;

function timeDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=
    time;
}
function timerFunction(){
    if(!clicked){
        clicked=true;
        if(time>0){
            var i=setInterval(function(){
                time--;
                timeDisplay();
            },1000);
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, the timer works, but it doesn't stop at zero and I don't understand why. Obviously I am very new to this, so any constructive criticism is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your `timerFunction` is run only once. The statement `if(time>0)` will execute only once and it will always be true because `time` is 20 initially.

You ideally want your `time` variable to be checked after regular intervals. Something you can do inside your `timeDisplay` function. To enable that, you need to ensure that unique interval id (here `intervalName`) can be accessed by `timeDisplay`.

```
var time=20;
var clicked=false;
var intervalName = null;
function timeDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=
    time;
      if(time == 0){
            clearInterval(intervalName);
        }
  
}
function timerFunction(){
    if(!clicked){
        clicked=true;
       intervalName = setInterval(function(){
                time--;
                timeDisplay();
            },1000);
        }
    
}
```

Note: I have replaced `i` with `intervalName`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a logic flaw. When you call timerFunction, you set the interval. But since that function is run only once, it will never check your if clause and it also doesn't set the intervall multiple times, as it would have, would it get executed more than once.

Hint: try to check for the time inside the setIntervall callback. I'm not 100% sure, but you can probably clear the intervall inside aswell with something like clearIntervall(this). Maybe you wanna try this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your if condition is checking for once and when the execution goes inside if it is not checking if condition again so you should have a condition inside interval function checking the value of time variable and clear interval.

`
var time=20;
var clicked=false;

```
function timeDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= time;
}
function timerFunction(){
    if(!clicked){
        clicked=true;
        var i= setInterval(function(){
                time--;
                if(time == 0){
                    clearInterval(i);
                }
                timeDisplay();
        },1000);
    }
}
```

`